# Slack Bot returning message from history

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

**QUESTION**

Here I am having a bot, when message with an attachment is posted in the slack channel, it should save the messages with some unique ids, and when we enter those id's  in the slack channel , the bot should return that message with attachment from the chat history

(just like how the public url to a message works -  https://workspace_name/archives/channel_name/token  ).

> If I attach an xml file in my channel, the bot should return that attachment(the specific message in which I added my attachment) from my channel's history when I type some id's associated with that message.

I am using this code : https://github.com/rampatra/jbot

**At present the issue is :-**

I tried to fetch the name of the file I am sharing to the channel ,
I was using event.getFile().getName() in SlackBot.java ( https://github.com/rampatra/jbot/blob/master/jbot-example/src/main/java/example/jbot/slack/SlackBot.java ) . and tried to display it .

```js
 @Controller(events = EventType.FILE_SHARED)
    public void onFileShared(WebSocketSession session, Event event) {
        logger.info("File shared: {}", event);
        System.out.println("file id : "+event.getFileId());
        System.out.println("file name :"+ event.getFile().getName());
    }
```

The bot should return the name of the file(1234.xml) I have shared. But it is coming as null value, but the id of the file("F........") is coming up properly.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON array containing the messages is the only format that the Slack API will return for a channel history. Its the same for `channel.history` and `conversations.history`.

To get additional information like channel names, user names, etc. you will need to parse the messages you received (e.g. for `<C12345678>` for a channel) and call additional APIs to retrieve and add that information. e.g. `conversations.info` for channel name or `users.info` for user name. Check out [this part](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#how_to_display_formatted_messages) of the Slack documentation for details on how to parse the Slack markup.

The same applies to attached and shared files. You will only get the link in the JSON array and then need to download the file by yourself. Note that you need to provide authentication for downloading private files from Slack to your app. ([see here](https://api.slack.com/types/file#authentication) for details):

Comment: Thanks. But this cant meet my requirement fully.

Comment: Please specify what you are missing and I am happy to extend my answer

Comment: Refering this code I developed my slack bot : " https://dzone.com/articles/make-slack-bots-in-java-in-minutes ". The the only requirement pending was making my bot to share the files shared with it when we enter some id or the name of the file. Now I tried to implement this using the url to the file. When the file name is messaged by someone in the channel as required the bot will return the file, but here for the time being I have hardcoded the file name. When I'm using the code in the above link I am able to get the user,channel and timestamp associated with my file share, but not filename.

Comment: Is there is some way to store the file name(Example:sample.xml) while it is being uploaded into the slack channel ? Here file.upload, conversation.history and channel.history can't be used.

Comment: 1. Would be great if you could add your new issue with the missing filename to the question instead of making it a comment.
2. You can indeed store the filename of an uploaded file with `files.upload`. Just use the optional `filename` property. It will then be stored in the file object.